# How to edit .bin disc image files?

Tags: binary

I want to edit bin disc image before burning to disc please help me. I tried using Winrar and 7zip but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also try ghex2 GNOME utilities. This give you the automated hex-to-ASCII on the side, as well as the various character/integer decodes at the bottom.